# How would you approach disembodied eyebrows?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

I recently started to dig deeper into animation and modeling of Nintendo's characters and I was wondering how they animated the disembodied eyebrows of Toon Link. What would your approach be? Did they change the texture of the whole head or maybe used simples planes that change with the facial expression?

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [cbsistatic.com](https://gamespot1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/mig/8/4/6/6/2238466-701110_20130917_001.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You can draw the face with the *Grease Pencil*. I'm not sure if and how it will work with this style of hair. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/7o5JGXU-V2Y

Comment: My guess would be it's a simple mesh placed in front of the head mesh (like a mask) and the eyes and eyebrows are a texture with alpha/cutout. And it is set to always render in front of the hair, even if it "should" be behind. I think in blender you can set something to always render in front of everything else, but I don't know if there's an option for this type of 'selective' render in front (cause it only should render in front of the hair, not other objects). Of course It could also be done with simple meshes for eyebrows, but it would still need to always render in front of the hair.